# Is there in Python an approach faster than a double "for" cycle to evaluate a function characterized by an internal vector?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-ndarray

I have the following function:

```
k=np.linspace(0,5,100) 
def f(x,y):
m=k
return sum(np.sin(m-x)*np.exp(-y**2))
```

I would like to obtain a 2D grid of values of f(x,y) evaluated on these two arrays:

```
x=np.linspace(0,4,30)
y=np.linspace(0,2,70)
```

Is there a way of calculation faster than a double "for" cycle like this one?

```
matrix=np.zeros((len(x),len(y)))
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        matrix[i,j]=f(x[i],y[j])
z=matrix.T
```

I tried to use the "numpy meshgrid" function in this way:

```
xx,yy=np.meshgrid(x, y)
z=f(xx,yy)
```

however I got the following error message:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,) (70,30).

Comment: A nested for-loop is going to be the best approach to enumerate all values; however, the real time-killer here is that all operations are synchronous. Therefore, before `matrix[0][1]` can be computed, `matrix[0][0]` must first be fully computed. I don't know NumPy well enough to say whether they provide a work around for this, but if you are willing to switch to standard arrays, you might get a decent speed boost by using generators, depending on how you end up using the computed results. Also worth noting, NumPy docs say matrix is deprecated in favor of regular arrays.

Comment: are you sure your function `f` is correct? why are subtracting a scalar `x` from an 100-sized array  `m`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a numpy approach.  If we start with your original array setup,

```
k = np.linspace(0,5,100)
x = np.linspace(0,4,30)
y = np.linspace(0,2,70)
```

then

```
matrix = np.sin(k[:,np.newaxis] - x).sum(axis = 0)[:,np.newaxis]*np.exp(-y**2)
```

returns the same (30,70) "matrix" calculated with the double "for" cycle.

For reference, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html outlines the broadcasting rules in numpy and https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/theory.broadcasting.html 
gives a nice illustration of using these rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
k=np.linspace(0,5,100) 
x=np.linspace(0,4,30)
y=np.linspace(0,2,70)

def f(x,y):
##    m=k
    return sum(np.sin(k-x)*np.exp(-y**2))

# original
def g():
    m = np.zeros((len(x),len(y)))
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(y)):
            m[i,j]=f(x[i],y[j])
    return m.T

# k.shape, x.shape, y.shape -> (100,), (30,), (70,)

# sine of each k minus each x
q = np.sin(k[:,None]-x)    # q.shape -> (100,30)

# [sine of each k minus each x] times [e to the negative (y squared)] 
r = np.exp(-y**2)    # r.shape --> (70,)
s = q[...,None] * r    # s.shape --> (100,30,70)

t = s.sum(0)
v = t.T    # v.shape -> (70,30)

assert np.all(np.isclose(v,g()))
assert np.all(v == g())
```

---

[Broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)